# Degree of the minimal polynomial of the sum of two integral elements over a UFD

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $D$ be an integral domain ($D$ is a noetherian UFD, if necessary) and let $a,b$ integral over $D$.
Let $f$ be the minimal polynomial of $a$ over $D$ and assume it is of degree $n>1$, and let $g$ be the minimal polynomial of $b$ over $D$ and assume it is of degree $m>1$.
Denote the minimal polynomial of $a+b$ over $D$ by $h$ and its degree by $d$;
it is known that $1 \leq d \leq nm$.

I wish to know when $d > \min \{n,m\}$.
Obviously, one has to demand that $a+b$ is not in $D$.

(Maybe adding the demand $D[a+b]= D[a+b,b]=D[a,b]$ guarantees
$d \geq \min \{n,m\}$, but I am interested in $>$. Actually, I prefer not to assume $D[a+b]=D[a,b]$.
Also, I do not want to demand that $n$ and $m$ are relatively prime).

Probably taking $D$ a field simplifies things, but I am interested in a noetherian UFD which is not a field.

Is my question too general (so nothing interesting can be said)?

Please notice the following somewhat relevant questions:
[How to prove that the sum and product of two algebraic numbers is algebraic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155122/how-to-prove-that-the-sum-and-product-of-two-algebraic-numbers-is-algebraic)
[Sums and products of algebraic numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141427/sums-and-products-of-algebraic-numbers?rq=1)

Comment: I think I've seen this also on MO. If it is so, please post a link to that thread (which I think contains a solution).

Comment: Thanks! But I have not found it; Perhaps you have seen this http://mathoverflow.net/questions/206396/degree-of-sum-of-integral-elements-over-a-ufd?