# Show that the sum of 2 algebraic integers is an algebraic integer using resultants

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, proof-writing, algebraic-number-theory, resultant

I've started working on algebraic numbers very recently for a memoir, that is I didn't study them in class.

I need them, and particularly algebraic integers, to prove a couple propositions which aren't the topic here. The thing is, I use the fact that a sum of algebraic integers is again an algebraic integer. I thought this wouldn't take too long to prove, however I can't finish my argument.. so any help would be welcome!

Here is what I've done so far:

I considered algebraic integers as roots of unitary polynomials of the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. Let $a,b$ be algebraic integers cancelled by unitary $P,Q \in \mathbb{Z}$, respectively. I've seen several prooves using Field extension or Galois Theory (for example on mathstack [Sums and products of algebraic numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141427/sums-and-products-of-algebraic-numbers) and [How to prove that the sum and product of two algebraic numbers is algebraic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155122/how-to-prove-that-the-sum-and-product-of-two-algebraic-numbers-is-algebraic)), but I haven't studied those, and I believe it can be proved using only resultants, so this is what I'm trying to to.

If $P(x) = \sum\limits_{i=0}^pa_ix^i$ and $Q(x) = \sum\limits_{i=0}^qb_ix^i$, then for $z= a + b$, $Q(z - x) = \sum\limits_{i=0}^qa_i(z-x)^i$.

This way $res_x(P(x),Q(z-x)) = (-1)^{pq}res_x(Q(z-x), R(z-x))$ (because the leading coefficient of $Q$ is 1) where $R$ is such that $P = AQ + R$ and $deg(R) < q$.

Then it seems that if we show this resultant is zero, it means $z$ is an algebraic integer, but why is that true ? And how can we express this resultant to get to this conclusion ?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

That's really a standard property of Resultants.  Let $P$ and $Q$ be two non-zero polynomials with coefficients in a field $F$ . Then $P$ and $Q$ have a common root in some extension of $F$ if and only if $res(P, Q) = 0$.  This follows from the product formula for $res(P,Q)$ involving the roots of $P$ and $Q$.

$P(x)$ and $Q(z-x)$ have the common root $a$, so that $res(P,Q)=0$.  Then since $a+b$ is a root of $res(P(x),Q(z-x))$ as a polynomial in $z$, $a+b$ is an algebraic integer.

Comment: Indeed, thanks for your help @Sharding! However, has the polynomial $res(P(x),Q(z-x))$ integer coefficients?